# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nesting scrollable in the same direction layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()) is not allowed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

While i was trying to put **LazyVerticalGrid** inside existing recyclerview, i got the following exception :

If i am giving fixed height then it is working like **modifier = Modifier.height(120.dp)** else not working with any other value even if i am giving **modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight()**. Here requirement is dynamic height as per the items inside, so can't gibve fixed height.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nesting scrollable in the same direction layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()) is not allowed. If you want to add a header before the list of items please take a look on LazyColumn component which has a DSL api which allows to first add a header via item() function and then the list of items via items().
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ScrollKt.assertNotNestingScrollableContainers-K40F9xA(Scroll.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$LazyList$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyList.kt:96)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$LazyList$1.invoke(LazyList.kt:95)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:345)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.measure-BRTryo0(InnerPlaceable.kt:43)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValuesModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:417)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:219)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.measure-BRTryo0(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.measure-BRTryo0(DelegatingLayoutNodeWrapper.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$3.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:100)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$remeasure$3.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:99)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:128)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:75)
```

Below is my code :

```
           productList?.let {
            LazyVerticalGrid(cells = GridCells.Fixed(2)) {
                items(productList) {product->
                    productImage(product = product)
                }
            }
    }
```

Any solution ??

Comment: Post your code pls